# Avoid the direct invocation of setup.py using build backend & build frontend

Tags: python, build, setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have recently read the article on avoiding direct invocation of setup.py using the new build backend approach(https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html).
I have configured my project as follows in the pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0", "setuptools", "cython", "toml"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Utilize the following code to initiate the build process:
`poetry build -f wheel`

I want to confirm if this setup aligns with the goal of avoiding direct usage of setup.py?  just to ensure that my packaging workflow follows the best practices outlined in the article.

Also if this is correct, I want some suggestions on below project structure
Package Structure:

```
my_project/
├── package
│   ├── pyproject.toml
        [build-system]
        requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0", "setuptools", "cython", "toml"]
        build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
│   ├── build.py( Includes cythonization, name of package passed to setup()=package)
│   ├── script.py(It runs the `"python -m build"` command to build the `package`,
                  & using `python setup.py build` to build `final_module`)
│   └── module1/
│       └── module2/
│           └── final_module/
│               ├── setup.py
│               └── module_files.py
```

Currently, I'm using the traditional approach with setup.py and building final_module
using the command `python setup.py build bdist_wheel`
However, I would like to switch to the modern build backend approach using Poetry
and ensure that I'm following the latest conventions. My`pyproject.toml`file is located
at the top level (package directory).

- What would be the recommended steps to switch from the traditional approach to the modern build backend approach?
- Given that the `pyproject.toml` file is at the top level, how can I configure Poetry to build the final_module subpackage? without creating pyproject.toml in subpackage.
- Are there any specific considerations I should keep in mind when restructuring my project and updating my build scripts?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.